# vba code suddenly encounters problems with enumeration

Tags: vba, outlook, enumeration, is-empty

This visual basic code related to outlook used to work without problems

```
Sub cmdExample()

    Dim myOlApp As Object
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myoSession = myOlApp.Session
    Set myoCalendar = myoSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
End Sub
```

Now I obtain the runtime error 5 (Invalid procedure call or argument)

Reason found from debugging: at runtime olFolderCalendar is empty (by the way, same problem for other enumerations like olAppointmentItem, olBusy). My  workaround in the above code is calling .GetDefaultFolder(9).

However I would rather use the enumerations and I would like to understand why all of them are empty.

Comment: You need a reference to the Outlook library under Tools > References.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass literal constants instead of numbers you need to add a COM reference to Outlook. Read more about that in the [How to Add an Object Library Reference in VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/add-object-library-reference-vba/) article.

[image]

Also, you may try to use the `Logon` method before getting the folder. See [NameSpace.Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) for more information.